# Which method does JAX-RS use for asynchronous communication?

Tags: web-services, rest, asynchronous, jax-rs

I need to work with a REST service (build with an JAX-RS implementation) in an heterogeneous environment, so I wondered how the abstractions of programming languages are converted to the real restful endpoints. I think most aspects are clear, but when it comes to asynchronous communications in REST I know several possibilities: keeping the connection open, returning a resource that can constantly be queried, chunked messages or the client transmits a callback resource.

My approach was to read the [JAX-RS 2.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf), but I think there is actually little stated about the REST implementation of asynchronous requests. Then I read the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html) and came to the conclusion that the JAX-RS implementations just keep the connection open for as long as the processing needs. So with "asynchronous" JAX-RS just refers to the blocking of methods on the server/client side and does not use any special behavior of REST. My first question: Is my analysis correct?

If this is the case, I have two new questions:

- Is this really compliant to the REST paradigm in respect to the stateless constraint?
- Considering the long-running processes that maybe work for days, is an open connection eventually automatically closed (e.g. by the OS or by a TCP timer)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

REST architecture has got nothing to do with asynchronous programming paradigms IMO. Asynchronous implementation using @Suspended and AsynResponse interface in JAX-RS involves suspending the thread which initiated the request

To answer your questions

1. 'So with "asynchronous" JAX-RS just refers to the blocking of methods on the server/client side and does not use any special behavior of REST'

-> REST has got nothing to do with async design in JAX-RS, but the way you design that Resource class and the setup the async method should involve RESTful principles.
Also, there is no 'blocking' as such - in fact its exactly the opposite. The I/O thread on server end is immediately suspended and returned to the container. The actual processing might still take a long time, but the real goal was to 'not block' and occupy threads. A Web container has limited number of threads dedicated to serving input requests. Prospective clients will get blocked if ALL the container threads are busy processing other clients. This is avoided by JAX-RS because it suspends the thread, returns it to the web container and responds on a different thread (internal server thread). All this increases the overall responsiveness of the application

2. 'Considering the long-running processes that maybe work for days, is an open connection eventually automatically closed (e.g. by the OS or by a TCP timer)?'

--> Not sure what would happen in case this happens. But its not necessary to have your clients waiting 'forever' - you can specify timeouts using the TimeoutHandler (guess you might have already read this)

Just my two cents!